# WordPress conflict with OOP jQuery Slider Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I've made a slider plugin and I'm trying to port it to WordPress. However, the code does not run when the "$" selector appears.

Here's the basic structure of my plugin, so you'll understand the OOP base I've built this on. I've tried alerts to see where the error is. It appears to be right after the first $ sign appears.

```
function slider(target, options) {
    /* Settings
     =============================== */
    var settings = $.extend({
        animation: "myanimation"            
    }, options);
    alert('qq');

    /* Variables
     =============================== */
    var self = this;


    /* Initialization
     =============================== */
    self.init = function() {}
}
```

And running the plugin:

```
jQuery(function($){
   var myslider = new slider();
   myslider.init();
})
```

Can you please help me on how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict().

[jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Even though I don't really understand why it doesnt work with an IIFE, noConflict did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), and passing `jQuery` as parameter:

```
(function($){
  function slider(target, options) {
    /* Settings */
    var settings = $.extend({
      animation: "myanimation"
    }, options);
    alert('qq');

    /* Variables */
    var self = this;


    /* Initialization */
    self.init = function() {}
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, by using this, when I create an instance of the slider, I get a "Object is not a function" error in the console. Still, thank you for the tip, was a good read.

Comment: Read this guide for implementing your function using an IIFE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures